# Are the data in Unrolled Linked Lists always ordered?

Tags: java

I have read the wikipedia page and some papers on it, but they don't make it clear whether all Unrolled Linked Lists data are in sequential order.  Is that what makes them better for caching than regular Linked Lists? I've also looked at different implementations, and I'm new to programming so it seems there is no comparison done before inserting it, so I am confused how these insertions are done.

When inserting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, I understand why 5 goes down with 6.
However, what is the reason why 6 continues after 5? Is it because the values must be compared and then 6 is inserted? Or is it because each node purposely is left with a null array space, and it is just being inserted in sequential order, and irrelevant to comparisons between the previously inserted value and currently inserted value?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmUbo.png)

Answer (score 0):

No. The numbers in the image just give the overall element index, *not* the content.

The "better for caching" part comes from the unrolled linked list being able to contain multiple data elements per list node and thus reducing the overhead of node creation and linkage. When the capacity of a single node is matched to the data carefully, this *may* lead to a performance boost. However, the unrolled linked list is not inherently "better" for each application.